Installing just ubuntu on an optane win 10 laptop
I have a laptop that was fairly good (Acer with Optane), but for some reason it started having problems with the optane module(it was degrading?) that I just couldn't solve, and just yesterday the BSOD... I got out my important files using command prompt, because to this day I just can't enter the system.
I have checked the forum for similar questions, but most of them are from people that wish to maintain a dual boot. I'm done with windows and intel optane, I would like to wipe out the entire disk with all of its partitions, and do a clean install of the latest Ubuntu version, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
So... this an update, after getting the ubuntu on an usb file, I tried to install it on my computer, but I really need to deactivate the optane mem, otherwise, ubuntu won't install, and if deactivate it, it seems like it's working until it's not. I took a picture with my phone, because, I don't know how to copy the log, but this is what I have:
enter image description here

Just like that? Do I need to first disable the optane mem on the bios?

no you don't. any bios setting will do. you might get warning during boot but a hard stop is almost always the video card.

I will try it then, hopefully everything goes well

Do "try ubuntu" from the usb drive first before installing, that will let you see if all the hardware is supported.

Have seen some with Optane where Optane is just a small 16 or 32GB boot cache for Windows. Some even replaced Optane module with newer NVMe drive. Is main drive also Optane? Intel discontinued Optane, Does your UEFI/BIOS have AHCI setting for drives?

Tried the balena way to create the ubuntu iso file, but to no avail, currently doing it with start up disk creator (on another ubuntu machine that I have). As for your question, I have the Sata mode rst with optane that I can change to AHCI
